# Chart.js: Dynamic Changing of Chart Type (Line to Bar as Example)

Tags: chart.js, vue.js

I am trying to hot swap chart types based on select box changes. If data needs to be updated, it changes.

So for example, on page load I create a chart like this:

```
var config = {
     type: 'line',
     data: {
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Some Label',
            data: this.values
        }]
     },
     options: {
         responsive: true
     }
}
var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
window.mychart = new Chart(context, config);
```

But then I change the combo box to a bar chart. I have tested the data with bar chart on page load, and it worked great.

Here's how I am trying to change the chart.

```
window.mychart.destroy();

// chartType = 'bar'
config.type = chartType;

var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
window.mychart = new Chart(context, config);

window.mychart.update();
window.mychart.render();
```

But nothing happens. The line chart remains. How can I dynamically change the chart type? (Even if it means destroying & re-creating the chart canvas).

**UPDATE**

Note it looks like it is actually destroying the chart, but keeps redrawing a line chart, even though I do `console.log(config.type);` and it returns `bar`, not `line`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## The Fix

- Destroy the old chart (to remove event listeners and clear the canvas)
- Make a deep copy of the config object
- Change the type of the copy
- Pass the copy instead of the original object.

[Here is a working jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ta9ogpvj/1/)

Example Overview:

```
var temp = jQuery.extend(true, {}, config);
temp.type = 'bar'; // The new chart type
myChart = new Chart(ctx, temp);
```

NOTE: Using version 2.0.1 of Chart.js

## Why this works

Chart.js modifies the config object you pass in. Because of that you can not just change 'config.type'. You could go into the modified object and change everything to the type you want, but it is much easier to just save the original config object.

Comment: Thanks for this. I found that this is an unexpected bug in 2.0 right now and will be fixed in the next release. But your deep copy solution works in the short term.

Answer (score 8):

Just to follow up that this is now fixed in v.2.1.3, as followed through by https://stackoverflow.com/users/239375/nathan

```
document.getElementById('changeToLine').onclick = function() {
  myChart.destroy();
  myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartData
  });
};
```

Confirmed fixed in latest version. Check out http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezJGPB and press the button under the chart to change it from a bar to a line chart.

Comment: this  works, but it would be great if we can just pass a chart type we want to render not the data part.

Answer (score 6):

In chart.js 3.8.0 you can do it like this:

```js
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    // ...
  },
  options: {
    // ...
  }
});

chart.config.type = "bar";
chart.update();
```

you can also change data and options this way

chart.js docs on updating:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

codepen example: https://codepen.io/3zbumban/pen/yLKMMJx

Comment: You can change data and options but chart type (!== dataset.type) is config and you cannot change it.

Comment: @PavelFrancírek it does work perfectly for me when switching between `bar` and `line` chart type. see: https://codepen.io/3zbumban/pen/yLKMMJx

Comment: If you use "pie" instead of "bar" type `chart.config.type = chart.config.type === "line" ? "pie" : "line"` pie is shown but rest (axes, rulers etc.) stays of original type.

Comment: @PavelFrancírek there is a simple reason and solution for this. I set Options that configure the scales. If you remove these when changing the chart type to `pie` it works. see: https://codepen.io/3zbumban/pen/YzaZJEe if you need further help you can contact me. Also pie charts and line/bar charts are for very different types of visualizations so it's most of the time not necessary to switch between them. (for example timeseries data)

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize that options don't reset when changing type. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: This approach should be marked as hack. You can't change `conifg` propery since its intended to be [readonly](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/types/index.d.ts#L477). Evenmore `config` may not have `type` at all, because type is determined per dataset and `config.type` is just fallback.

Answer (score 3):

No need to destroy and re-create, you just have to change the type from the chart's config variable then update the chart.

```
var chartCfg = {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data
};

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, chartCfg );

function changeToBar() {
    chartCfg.type = "bar";
    myChart.update();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternate solution can be as simple as creating both the charts in separate Div elements. Then as per your condition just make one visible and hide other in the javascript. This should serve the purpose you may have for changing the chart type for your requirement.

Comment: I am trying to experiment with a "chart builder" of sorts. Choose chart type, then data sources, and so on. So essentially I only want one chart type on the page, and want to swap them in and out as necessary.

Comment: One solution I can think of is to have different Div templates, with separate elements for different chart types. Then in the area where you want to display your chart, have a main parent Div element. Based on the selection of the chart type, you can add/remove child Div element corresponding to the chart type selected. I believe you will get better performance too this way.

Answer (score 1):

In ChartJS, the chart type can also be changed easily like chart data. Following example might be helpful

```
        my_chart.type = 'bar';
        my_chart.update();
```

Comment: I could not get this method to work. updating other parameters worked while updating type did not.

Answer (score 0):

In ChartJS 3, :

```
var options = // your options.
var data = { ...myChart.data }; // deep copy of the data
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart_id').getContext('2d');

myChart.destroy()

/// Modify ctx or data if you need to.

myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: chart_type,
        data: data
});

Chart.options = options;
myChart.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its 2024 and I am working on a Legacy Project so I am using Chart.js v2.7.2. If you are starting a new project use the current version.
This is what worked for me

```js
//in my adjax beforesend function
beforeSend: function(){
    helper.btnLoading(btn);
    //remove the canvas element entirely
    $("#chartResultWrapper").remove();
},

//in my adjax success function
success: function(response){
  let data = response.result;
  
  //add the canvas element to the dom with your targetted ID
  $("#resultsBody").prepend('<canvas id="chartResultWrapper"></canvas>');

  createChart(response.result, type);
},
```

```html
<div class="card-body" id="resultsBody">
        <canvas id="chartResultWrapper"></canvas>
        <div class="mt-4" id="mainResult">
      <small class="text-muted">No data available</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

The rest of your code should remain same. Hopes it works for your case