# chart.js mixed chart types

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this example from `chart.js` [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-mixed-chart-types):

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'],
        datasets: [
            {
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'Bar Component',
                data: [10, 20, 30],
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                label: 'Line Component',
                data: [30, 20, 10],
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

It works fine. However, my intention is to change the type dynamically.

I am aware that there is `getDatasetMeta()` method, that you can apply to your chart instance, and if I output the result it returns to the console I get something like this:

```
{
    bar: true,
    controller: ChartElement,
    data: Array[...],
    dataset: null,
    hidden: false,
    type: 'bar',
    ...
}
```

I can control the appearance of a certain dataset via `hidden` property, though if I change `type` to `line` and invoke `update()` it won't re-render.

So, is there a way to dynamically change dataset type?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround here: [Chart.js: Dynamic Changing of Chart Type (Line to Bar as Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949343/chart-js-dynamic-changing-of-chart-type-line-to-bar-as-example)

Sad that it's not yet supported officially.