# ChartJS, reposition elements and scale with custom plugin

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When you change graph type from 'bar' to 'line', the x-axes and the elements on the graph reposition themself, so the elements fit on the canvas.

Now I use this plugin to have a multi colored line charts with a fill. And I think that may cause not rearange the elements/scale.

Bar charts use an other kind of scale (tick in the middel)

So from Bar to Line chart this doesn't cause much trouble because al elements are still in the canvas. But from Line to Bar, it makes half of the first and the last bar dissapear from the canvas.

So from Bar to Line:

[image: Bar to Line 1]
[image: Bar to Line 2]

The first and last dots are not aligned to the right and left side of the canvas, but it is at least visable.

But from Line to Bar:

[image: Line to Bar 1]
[image]

The first and last bar don't fit in the canvas.

I have tried to use `instance.update()`,  `instance.render(instane.config)` but this doesn't seem to work.

Is there any method to redraw/reposition all elements in the chart?
Or some method I should override in the multi color plugin?

```
Chart.plugins.register({

    id: "multiColoredLine",

    beforeInit: function(chart, options) {
        if (!pluginOptions.enable) return;
    },

    afterDatasetsUpdate: function(chart, options) {
        //here do i do some things to calculate gradient etc 
        //and put it in dataset and meta so after this
    }
```

Comment: [Chart.js: Dynamic Changing of Chart Type (Line to Bar as Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949343/chart-js-dynamic-changing-of-chart-type-line-to-bar-as-example) this can be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't work. Somehow it still draws the lines/bars at the wrong place. Doesn't reposition the ticks on the axis and it's elements.
Seems like some position values are copied and used from the config somewhere.

Comment: Please share your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.