# chart js Try to update the chart type

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I have a multiple data's with a different label name's , Try to update the chart type

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: myData
});

myData = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Data, baby!",
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255, 0.25)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(190, 99, 255)',
            data: dataBaby,
          },
            {
            label: "More data, baby!",
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.25)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: moreDataBaby,
        }]
    };
```

And I have updated the chart type with ajax .. `myChart.type = "Bar"` And used `myChart.update();`

Now am getting the chart type as **Bar** , but the alignment of the chart is not proper .. It shows improper data ..even-though i have only labels , but i want in timeline format.

[Chart js Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1XOS.png)

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36988676/2358409

Comment: agree with @uminder, best way is destroying the old chart and re-render a chart with new type